# jQuery random for duplicated html/jquery fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my jQuery script and html script. I have a dropdown menu and for the selected option there is a random generated number showed in the supplies field (voorraad). but when I clone that field with my add button the options work only on one supplies field. does someone know how to fix this?

the solution I want is that for each dropdown menu the random generated numbers shows in the right supplies field

html

```
<p id="drops">
    <section id="down">
            <select size ="1" name="">
            <option value="" selected="default">Geen voorkeur</option>
            <option value="">Hatseflats Pharma</option>
            <option value="">ZuydGeest</option>
            <option value="">Pharmalicious</option>
            <option value="">Karma op die Pharma</option>
            <option value="">Boemklats Pharma</option>
           </select>
      <select size ="1" name="" class="medicijnen" onchange="document.getElementsByName('voorraad').value = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))">
            <option value="" selected="default" disabled="default">Kies een product</option>
            <option value="">Paracetamol 5g</option>
            <option value="">Paracetamol 10g</option>
            <option value="">Aspirine 5g</option>
            <option value="">Aspirine 15g</option>
            <option value="">Donperidon 5g</option>
            <option value="">Donperidon 10g</option>
            <option value="">Ergonimon 6g</option>


           </select>
           <label>Voorraad: </label> <input type="text" id="medicijnen" name="voorraad"  size="5" readonly>
           <label>Aantal:</label> <input size="5" type="text" name="aantal">
         <img src="delete.png" height="16"  class="remove" id="rmv" width="16"/>
           </section>
       </p>
    <p>
        <button class="add" id="btn" value="add field">Bestelregel toevoegen</button>
    </p>
```

and my part of the jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var counter = 1;

    $("#btn").live("click", function() {
        $("#down:first").clone().appendTo("#drops").addClass("lang" + counter);
        counter++;
        return false;
    });

    $("#rmv").live('click', function() {
        if (counter > 1) { //Only apply if the lang field is more than 1
            counter = counter - 1;
            $("#down:last").remove();
        }
        return false;
    });

});
    $(".medicijnen").change(function() {
    var voorraad = 0;
    $.each($(".medicijnen") , function(){
        voorraad = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1
        });
    $("#medicijnen").val(voorraad)
    });
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle of this?

Comment: `ID` should be unique.

Comment: ok sec wil make a fiddle and trying with the id

Comment: oops forgot the cloning part. I added it. also how do you make a ID unique?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want "Voorraad" text box to be filled with a random number when there is a selection in the "Kies een product" list box correct?

If so, you don't need to use an inline js trigger to engage it. Here is a jquery script that will do the job for you:

```
$('.medicijnen').change(function(){
    var stock = Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1;
    $('#medicijnen').val(stock);
});
```

Also, here is the JSlint of the code working (note I had to change some of the text to understand what was going on) - http://jsfiddle.net/t2D6S/

Hopefully this should get you on the right path.

UPDATE:
So I was able to get the list to replicate, and I was also able to get the Stock to populate, however the stock only populates on the first one and not on any other one.

Here is the updated fiddle = http://jsfiddle.net/q8f4K/

Sorry I couldn't be of any more help. Maybe someone else can fix the last bit.

Comment: not exactly. when you run the html. you get 2 dropdown and 2 textfield. I can change it all to english if you want. the problem is when I press the button (bestelregel toevoegen in english add order) all of the dropdowns and textfield are cloned. after the cloning  if I select one of the second dropdowns where it says kies product (in english chose product) the value of that random always go to the first supplies text field. so I only can see 1 random supply at the time. and nog next to each

Comment: I see, give me a bit. I think I can help you with that.